# How do we force a refresh during an MVC Redirect from a POST? Page is only refreshed once the GET has been reached

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Build")]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public virtual ActionResult Build(string clientData = null)
{
    DAMEClientData dameClientData = null;
    if (clientData != null)
    {
        dameClientData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DAMEClientData>(clientData);
    }
    var model = new BuildViewModel();
    model.OrderID = CurrentSession.OrderID.GetValueOrDefault();
    model.OrderItemID = CurrentSession.OrderItemID.GetValueOrDefault();
    model.MaterialID = CurrentSession.MaterialID.GetValueOrDefault();
    helper.Populate(model, CurrentSession, DAMEEditAction.Post, dameClientData);
    if (clientData == null)
    {
        var materialId = this.helper.SaveSession(CurrentSession);
        return RedirectToAction("Build", new 
            { 
                OrderID = model.OrderID,
                OrderItemID = model.OrderItemID,
                MaterialID = materialId,
                editAction = DAMEEditAction.Post
            }
        );
    }
    return View("Build", model);
}
```

The refresh only happens once the page has hit the HttpGet method, while we're trying to
refresh and change the url in the process.

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Build")]
public virtual ActionResult Build(int? OrderID, int? OrderItemID, int? MaterialID, string editAction)
{
    if (editAction.ParseEnum<DAMEEditAction>() ==  DAMEEditAction.FirstLoad && 
        CurrentSession.DAMEEditAction != DAMEEditAction.FirstLoad)
    {
        CurrentSession = new DAMESession();
        CurrentSession.DAMEEditAction = DAMEEditAction.FirstLoad;
    }

    var model = new BuildViewModel
    {
        OrderID = OrderID.GetValueOrDefault(),
        OrderItemID = OrderItemID.GetValueOrDefault(),
        MaterialID = MaterialID.GetValueOrDefault()
    };

    try
    {
        if (OrderID.GetValueOrDefault() == 0 || 
            OrderItemID.GetValueOrDefault() == 0 || 
            MaterialID.GetValueOrDefault() == 0)
            return new RedirectResult("~/DAME/Editor/SessionExpired");
        CurrentSession.OrderID = OrderID;
        CurrentSession.OrderItemID = OrderItemID;
        CurrentSession.MaterialID = MaterialID;

        model = helper.Populate(model, CurrentSession, DAMEEditAction.Load);
        CurrentSession.DAMEEditAction = DAMEEditAction.Load;
        var buildName = settingsProvider.GetStringValue("BuildName");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(buildName)) buildName = $"(Build name: {buildName})";
        ViewBag.BuildName = buildName;
        return View(model);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {                
        const string error = "An error occurred populating";
        this.logger.Error(error, e);
        model.ErrorMessage = error;
        return View(model);
    }
}

// from the view

<button id="saveDraftBtn" type="submit" name="NavigationButton" href="@saveSessionUrl" class="btn btn-primary btn-next btn-save-draft"  style="visibility: @Html.Raw(disabledText)">
    <span>@SaveDraft</span> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></i>
</button>
```

As stated in the code, we're trying to change the url parameter with a new parameter. The materialId is our new parameter. This is not an Ajax call so I would expect it to refresh. Button type is submit.